# Можно ли управлять кэш-памятью процессора программно?

Tags: ассемблер

Существуют ли способы управления кэш-памятью процессора с помощью языка Ассемблера? Или это осуществляется на аппаратном уровне?

Comment: Зависит от архитектуры процессора. Вы о каком и что именно хотите делать с кэшем?

Comment: @avp Да тот же i386. Хранить временные данные, например.

Comment: Был ли вообще кэш в i386 [большой вопрос](http://infotags.ru/cech1.htm) (в i386 SL от 1990 года на чипе был контроллер внешней кэш-памяти). Что же касается управления хранением данных в кэше, надо смотреть в документации на интересующий  вас процессор, есть ли в  нем биты в управляющих регистрах, запрещающие вытеснение избранных строк кэша.

Comment: @avp Спасибо!
А есть ли возможность отследить содержимое кэша?

Comment: @Андрей Я удалил ответ, так как он не соответствует действительности. Копать глубоко и изучать эту тему, что бы написать вменяемый ответ ломает и может занять пару дней. Вот почитайте https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-vol-2a-manual.pdf  Поиском  в документе посмотрите все со словом "cache". в общем виде инструкции для управления кешем существуют, как минимум кеш можно выборочно сбрасывать и заказывать выборку конкретных данных.

Comment: @Андрей Правда это явно не то, что вы ожидали, использовать кеш явно для хранения данных не связанных с конкретными адресами оперативной памяти на сколько я понимаю нельзя. по крайней мере все инструкции управления кешем как операнд принимают адрес в памяти, содержащий данные с кешем которых надо работать

Comment: @Андрей Что касается количества тактов на запрос памяти, они зависят от выравненности данных. для не выравненных данных может потребоваться два цикла шины вместо одного. как это соотносится с тактами не знаю, ведь у шины другая частота и другие такты

Comment: @Mike То есть, адрес данных в ОЗУ?
Получается, можно занять память в ОЗУ, и автоматически (предположение) такой же размер памяти выделится в кэше. Далее, как я понимаю, можно работать с данными в кэш-памяти без сброса их в ОЗУ?

Comment: @Андрей По хорошему в большинстве случаев за этим следить вообще не надо. как я писал работа всегда происходит с кешем. и чтение и запись. а общение процессора с памятью происходит асинхронно, он сам решает когда ему прочитать и когда записать изменения в память. но рано или поздно сброс в память все равно произойдет.

Comment: И даже если вы выберете какие то данные явно, никто не сказал, что на следующей инструкции данные еще будут в кеше. ведь когда вы получили данные ОС может переключить задачу и та будет работать со своими данными и кеш будет использован под них. т.е. получить реальные преимущества от управления кешем вы сможете только если ваша программа будет выполнятся в однопользовательском режиме вместо операционной системы

Comment: @Mike Теоретически ОС можно как раз спроектировать с учётом эффективного использования кэш-памяти. Теоретически :)

Comment: @Андрей вы посмотрите сколько современные процессы занимают памяти. средний процесс в разы превышает размер кеша. А процессов в системе сотня и управление постоянно скачет между ними... И что бы ОС что то могла спланировать она должна заставить процессы отвечать определенным требованиям.

Comment: @Mike Тогда можно писать программы, которые бы работали без ОС. Выполняющие вычисления, например.
Хотя... Уже кажется, что смысл данной затеи теряется.

Comment: Да он вообще небольшой, смысл этот. держите данные компактно, что бы данные используемые совместно лежали рядом и оказывались в одной строке кеша (кеш ведь читается большими кусками, обычно не менее 64 байт). выравнивайте структуры. не забывайте, что у вас есть 12 регистров общего назначения, вот в них точно операции гораздо быстрее. используйте расширения типа mmx, sse, когда это подходит. А остальное процессор сделает за вас и постарается сделать это оптимально

Comment: @Mike Спасибо за ответы :)